# How do I process a partial order of tasks concurrently using Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, concurrency, perl-data-structures

I have a partially ordered set of tasks, where for each task all of the tasks that are strictly before it in the partial order must be executed before it can be executed. I want to execute tasks which are not related (either before or after one other) concurrently to try to minimise the total execution time - but without starting a task before its dependencies are completed.

The tasks will run as (non-perl) child processes.

How should I approach solving a problem like this using Perl? What concurrency control facilities and data structures are available?

Comment: A cheat: you can also write a Makefile to describe dependencies and do e.g. `make -j 4` for a max of 4 concurrent workers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a hash of arrays. For each task, all its prerequisities will be mentioned in the corresponding array:

```
$prereq{task1} = [qw/task2 task3 task4/];
```

I would keep completed tasks in a different hash, and then just

```
my @prereq = @{ $prereq{$task} };
if (@prereq == grep exists $completed{$_}, @prereq) {
    run($task);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a full solution is [NP-complete](http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/transputer/chapter9/chap9-1.html).

As for a partial solution, I would use some form of reference counting to determine which jobs are ready to run, [Forks::Super::Job](http://search.cpan.org/~mob/Forks-Super-0.56/lib/Forks/Super/Job.pm) to run the background jobs and check their statuses and [POSIX::pause](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod) to sleep when maximum number of jobs is spawned.

No threads are involved since you're already dealing with separate processes.

Read the first link for possible algorithms/heuristics to determine runnable jobs' priorities.